# Help selecting AC power adapter for DC car monitor

Tags: power-supply

I purchased a Pyle 9" TFT monitor for use in an automobile with back-up camera. The wiring is designed to connect directly into the car's harness. I have no info on the electrical requirements other than, of course, 12V from the car.

I plan to use this monitor inside to make my nephew a headboard with digital photo/video/netflix frame. I've wired some indoor 12V lighting before, but probably just got lucky. I want to know if a similar power supply will work here? I'm looking at a DC 12V 2A Power Supply Adapter for 110V-240V AC 50/60hZ (whatever that means?). Does that sound like that will work? Should I get the 3A version to be sure since I read on this website the whole "amps are like apples" analogy?

Comment: Is it [this one](http://www.pyleaudio.com/sku/PLHRQD9W/9-Quad-TFTLCD-Video-Monitor-wHeadrest-Shroud-RCA-Connectors%28White%29)? The manual for that one says 6W.

Comment: Not so much a duplicate as that the manufacturer doesn't make it easy to determine the power consumption.  The online manuals don't mention it, and I only found it because one online shop that sells them put it in their description.

Comment: @JRE: It's definitely in the manual for both models.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams You are right, I found it after taking a second look in the manual.  I had started out looking for current and completely missed the power entry in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a typo and you meant the Pyle PLHR78W, I [find](http://www.parts-express.com/pyle-plhr78w-7-widescreen-headrest-monitor-white--267-7010) that it consumes 8Watts, which would be 0.67 Amperes at 12Volts.  Your 2Amp, 12Volt power supply should be fine.

I can't find PLHRQD8W anywhere, which is why I assume your voice type software mangled it.  Even if not, the power consumption should be comparable - the power consumption seems to be coded into the model number, and both say 8W.